# Unable to read from UNIX socket using net.Conn.Read

Tags: go, unix-socket

I'm trying to do simple UNIX socket communication with a service using GO. For testing I've created a socket like so:

```
$ nc -vlU /tmp/sock
Bound on /tmp/sock
Listening on /tmp/sock
```

And in GO, I `net.Dial` and try to write something, then read. I see the written data in the `nc` console, so I know that is working. But the `net.Conn.Read` operation appears non-blocking and will return immediately with zero length. From everything I've read and the example I've seen, this operation should block.

```
buf := make([]byte, 0, 4096)
ctl, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/sock")
for {
    ctl.Write([]byte("test write\n"))
    n, err := ctl.Read(buf)
    fmt.Printf("Len:%v, Data:%v, err:%v", n, buf, err)
}
```

I see the connection come through and data written ...

```
Connection received on /tmp/sock
test write
test write
test write
test write
...
```

But the GO console loops without blocking, reporting a zero length and no error

```
Len:0, Data:[], err:<nil>
Len:0, Data:[], err:<nil>
Len:0, Data:[], err:<nil>
Len:0, Data:[], err:<nil>
...
```

And of course if I type anything into the `nc` console nothing interesting happens in the GO program output.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the `err` result of `Read`?

Comment: @BurakSerdar `nil`. There is no error. It just returns zero length and no error in a loop.

Comment: @sherrellbc: no error and 0 byte read indicate a connection close by the peer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich. I've noticed that it continues to loop like this if I kill the `nc` process. But while it's looping I continue to see the written data show up in the `nc` console (if I add a `net.Conn.Write` call in the loop). So the connection remains valid. I updated the post to reflect this.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, a connection close should return io.EOF

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have that check in my code (that I did not post) for when `net.Conn.Read` returns an err. But there is no error. The read does not block and there is no err returned. I see the _written_ data in the `nc` console so the connection is valid because the data gets through. I just can't read anything for some reason.

Comment: @JimB I do that too (in code not posted). That works fine. I can write data without issue. Only the read seems to fail.

Comment: @sherrellbc: `strace` shows that the socket is opened as non-blocking, epoll is used for polling and never actually a `read` occurs (likely since epoll never returns). Thus `ctl.Read` does not seem to actually cause a read but it just caused the currently read data from polling the socket - which are none. It is the same with TCP btw

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Odd. I tried something like this about a year ago and it worked fine at the time (just the use of UNIX sockets in general). I used strace and noticed the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### short answer

```
buf := make([]byte, 0, 4096)
```

this code make a buffer with `len=0`!!!

do it like

```
buf := make([]byte, 4096)
```

### example

this is some example i used, and they all works.

In practice, socket read and write should happen in `two goroutines`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    buf := make([]byte, 0, 4096)
    fmt.Println(buf)
    main03()
}

func main01() {
    // nc -vlU /tmp/sock0120
    ctl, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/sock0120")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(ctl)
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        ctl.Write([]byte("test write\n"))
        msg, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
        fmt.Printf("Len:%v, Data:%v, err:%v\n", len(msg), msg, err)
    }
}

func main02() {
    // nc -vlU /tmp/sock0120
    buf := make([]byte, 4)
    ctl, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/sock0120")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    reader := bufio.NewReader(ctl)
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        ctl.Write([]byte("test write\n"))
        n, err := io.ReadFull(reader, buf)
        fmt.Printf("Len:%v, Data:%v, err:%v\n", n, buf, err)
    }
}

func main03() {
    // nc -vlU /tmp/sock0120
    buf := make([]byte, 4)
    ctl, err := net.Dial("unix", "/tmp/sock0120")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        ctl.Write([]byte("test write\n"))
        n, err := ctl.Read(buf)
        fmt.Printf("Len:%v, Data:%v, err:%v\n", n, buf, err)
    }
}
```

Comment: This was it. Oof. What a waste of time on such a simple issue. I had been looking at code that was using both a fixed-size slice (for each recv) and one with zero length (the data buffer) and just copied `make([]byte, 0, N)` twice.

Comment: @sherrellbc I had some experience like yours some times. Strange behavior always goes to simple  bug.